# Adding data to a UITableView while the UITableView is visible?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've read every post here on SO regarding UITableView and reloadData, and nothing I've found has worked for me.

In the UI builder I have a UIViewController xib file with a UIView in it, and on that UIView, a UITableView. My UIViewController subclass is references as the File Owner for the xib. My subclass is a UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate, and I've wired up the dataSource and delegate referencing outlets to point to the UITableView in the UI builder. I've linked the UITableView in builder to the IBOutlet defined in my subclass.

Initially when the UITableView is displayed, the underlying NSMutableArray that I'm using as the data source has no data it, so the UITableView is empty as expected.

Later on, I modify the array, adding data to it.

I then have tried the following to refresh the view of the UITableView, all to no avail:

- Called [myTableView reloadData] after changing my array
- Called [myTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
- Called insertRowsAtIndexPaths on the myTableView, thinking I might need to actually tell it which row to update.

None of these work. However, the data is there and everything seems to be wired up OK, as whenever I drag the UITableView up and release, so that the first row has temporarily disappeared, suddenly it does display the expected content when it comes back into view.

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that the other delegate method - numberOfRowsInSection - is not performing correctly. Or it could of course be numberOfSectionsInTableView. One or both of them is returning zero after the reload.

Comment: I have not implemented numberOfSectionsInTableView, only numberOfRowsInSection. I wasn't aware the numberOfSectionsInTableView was required if you only have one section in your tableview, but I will give that a try (presumably it just needs to return 1). However, I'm skeptical because if I start out with a full array of data, all the data appears. In this situation, the numberOfSectionsInTableView is still not present, and yet it works...

Comment: @xj1200 Even though I had all of the delegate methods working properly, ultimately you were on the right track here. See my answer for details.

Comment: makes sense. Great you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I had everything wired up correctly, I was chasing my tail. Ultimately the problem was not with the UITable at all, and not with the underlying array being used as the basis for my UITableView, but with the dictionary I was using to generate the text for each cell!

The array was being updated correctly, then reloadData was being called. But the dictionary wasn't being loaded with the necessary data until AFTER reloadData was being called. So the UITable was being "populated" with the right number of rows, but they all appeared blank, making it seem like things weren't working at all.

Once I took the trailer trash method of NSLogging some debugging data for each call to my UITableView delegates, it became obvious that things were being called as expected, but the data was not being pulled correctly for each cell.

Whew!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you right to call `[tableView reloadData]`

But you may want to set the [array count] in this method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
```

And within

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath];}
```

This should allow you show the data from the array.

Comment: Yeah, as a delegate, I am implementing those routines in my subclass already. They use an NSMutableArray. So that should be working here.